# Is there a way to save variables in debugger mode to global environment?

Tags: r, debugging, global-variables

I am using the `browser()` function to debug my code.
I would like to save all the variables to the global environment, such that when I exit the debugging mode they will be available.

I know how to do this for a single variable. E.g. if I want to save `df`:

```
df <<- df
```

Is there a way to save all of the variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `*apply()`, `ls()`, and `assign()`. In a fresh R session, I created the following function:

```
f <- function() {
    x <- 1
    y <- 2
    z <- 3
    return(x + y + z)
}

ls()
# [1] "f"
```

I then ran `f()` using `debug()`, and just before the `return()` statement, executed the following from the console:

```
lapply(ls(), function(o) assign(x = o, value = get(o), envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

Then, after the function's execution ended, checked my global environment:

```
ls()
# [1] "f" "x" "y" "z"
```